# Truncating words in handlebars + rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

I want to truncate {{location}}. Is there anyway to mix the rails .truncate helper in my handlebars template? Or do I need to use a Handlebars truncate helper?

Thanks!

**template.hbs.erb**

```
<li>{{location}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add helpers to the Handlebars template so those that are working on the front end can easily modify the settings without backend support. Keeps everything clean.

If you would like the code for the trucate words Handlebar helper you can find it here:

https://gist.github.com/sshadmand/a3257ab23d3a76017431

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('truncwords', function(text, length) {
        words = text.split(" ");
        new_text = text;
        if (words.length > length){
            new_text = "";
            for (var i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
               new_text += words[i] + " ";
            }  
            new_text = new_text.trim() + "..."          
        }
        return new_text;
    });
```